# How can I check ordering of items in a Python Enum?

Tags: python, enums

I have an `enum.Enum` subclass:

```py
class MyEnum(Enum):
    A = "apple"
    C = "cherry"
    B = "banana"
```

and I want to be able to use `<` and `>` to see if a given member comes before or after another one in the definition order, so I could do something like this:

```py
>>> MyEnum.A < MyEnum.B
True
>>> MyEnum.B >= MyEnum.C
True
>>> MyEnum.C < MyEnum.A
False
```

based on where the values appear in the definitions of the enum, **not** the enum values themselves. I know that Enums preserve order, but there is no way of finding which came first. How can I accomplish this in Python 3.7?

Comment: Why not name the fields as apple, cherry,.... with orderable values? The point of an enum is generally to have a comprehensive name but a practical value. You have an incomprehensive name for an impractical value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to override comparison operators and somehow check the order of names of compared enum members. I found that `_member_names_` preserve the order of defined members:

```
from enum import Enum
import functools


@functools.total_ordering
class MyEnum(Enum):
    A = "apple"
    C = "cherry"
    B = "banana"

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, MyEnum):
            return (
                self._member_names_.index(self.name) ==
                self._member_names_.index(other.name)
            )
        return NotImplemented

    def __gt__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, MyEnum):
            return (
                self._member_names_.index(self.name) >
                self._member_names_.index(other.name)
            )
        return NotImplemented


print(MyEnum.A < MyEnum.B)  # True
print(MyEnum.B >= MyEnum.C)  # True
print(MyEnum.C < MyEnum.A)  # False
```

Comment: Is `__eq__` needed for `functools.total_ordering`?  Because `Enum` comes with an `__eq__` that is much more efficient.

Comment: Oh, I see, Enum uses default `object.__eq__`. So answering your question: yes, without reimplementing `__eq__` my code will be more efficient. I implemented it because `functools.total_ordering` says it is needed: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.total_ordering - "the class should supply an `__eq__()` method.". Maybe I just misunderstood this wording.

Comment: Ah, I was mistaken -- `Enum` does not supply its own `__eq__`.

Comment: @EthanFurman but accidentally default implementation of `object.__eq__` works correctly for MyEnum. Try to remove `__eq__` method from MyEnum - all comparisons will be correct.

Comment: That's not an accident.  ;-)  I had just forgotten that I didn't need to implement `__eq__` because `object.__eq__` had the behavior we wanted.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [IntEnums](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#enum.IntEnum) instead and use better names:

```
import enum

class Fruits(enum.IntEnum):
    Apple = 0
    Cherry = 1
    Banana = 2

print(Fruits.Apple < Fruits.Banana) 
print(Fruits.Banana >= Fruits.Cherry) 
print(Fruits.Cherry < Fruits.Apple)
```

Output:

```
True
True
False
```

[IntEnums](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#enum.IntEnum) can be compared to each other and normal ints - so `Fruits.Apple < 1000` is valid.

You can get the name or value from it like this:

```
>>> print(Fruits.Apple.name)
Apple

>>> print(Fruits.Apple.value)
0
```

Comment: my problem is that the values have to be something other than ints

Comment: `IntEnum` should only be used when compatibility with existing values is needed.

Comment: @Ethan Why? [Comparison](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#comparisons) especially mentions IntEnum as exception from the rule that Enums are not comparible. Your solution is neater then using IntEnum, but I was unable to find any "Don't do this" regarding using IntEnums if you want comparable Enums.

Comment: Good point; down-vote removed.  The "why" is that using `IntEnum` (or `StrEnum`, etc.) opens up the possibility of mistakenly comparing an enum against a different enum class or non-enum value -- in other words, you lose some type-safety.

Answer (score 2):

Using the [`OrderedEnum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#orderedenum) recipe as a start, it is easy to create your own ordered enum base class:

```
class OrderedEnum(Enum):

    def __init__(self, value, *args, **kwds):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwds)
        self.__order = len(self.__class__)

    def __ge__(self, other):
        if self.__class__ is other.__class__:
            return self.__order >= other.__order
        return NotImplemented

    def __gt__(self, other):
        if self.__class__ is other.__class__:
            return self.__order > other.__order
        return NotImplemented

    def __le__(self, other):
        if self.__class__ is other.__class__:
            return self.__order <= other.__order
        return NotImplemented

    def __lt__(self, other):
        if self.__class__ is other.__class__:
            return self.__order < other.__order
        return NotImplemented
```

And your example class becomes:

```
class MyEnum(OrderedEnum):
    A = "apple"
    C = "cherry"
    B = "banana"
```

Comment: using the incrementing `len(self.__class__)` is cool. `super().__init__(*args, **kwds)` should be `super().__init__()`

Comment: @PatrickArtner: It's good practice to strip out the arguments needed for one's own class, and pass any others up the chain.  If any were given to `OrderedEnum`, they should be passed up where they can either be used, or hit the end of the chain and raise an error.

Comment: For me `super().__init__(*args, **kwds)` gives `TypeError: object.__init__() takes no parameters` in python 3.6 - so code does not work?

Comment: @PatrickArtner:  Ah, I was using `aenum` when I tested, and it isn't calling `super()`.  I'll look into fixing that.  Meanwhile, I adjusted the `__init__` line to pull out `value`.  Thanks for being persistent!

Answer (score 0):

you can override those operators in your enum class, it will be better for you to read about the data model [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html)

if i would need to do it i would probably create a list of the elements ordered, and check it when calling does function, or change any element to be a tuple with index, and change the `__get__` function

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your Enum class's `__dict__` preserves Python 3.7's dictionary ordering semantics, you can get the order of the members like this:

```
>>> class E(enum.Enum):
...    A = 'apple'
...    C = 'cherry'
...    B = 'banana'
... 
>>> 
>>> members = [v for v in E.__dict__.values() if isinstance(v, E)]
>>> members
[<E.A: 'apple'>, <E.C: 'cherry'>, <E.B: 'banana'>]
```

The comparisons can then be made based on positions in the list.