# How to compare string enums in python

Tags: python, enums

Let's say I have `MyEnum` enum, and I want to define total ordering for it. My approach is:

```py
from enum import Enum
from functools import total_ordering

@total_ordering
class MyEnum(Enum):
    ONE = "one",
    TWO = "two",
    THREE = "three",

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, MyEnum):
            return False
        return self.value == other.value

    def __hash__(self):
        return self.value.__hash__()

    def __le__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, MyEnum):
            return False

        enum2int = {
            MyEnum.ONE: 1,
            MyEnum.TWO: 2,
            MyEnum.THREE: 3,
        }
        
        return enum2int[self] < enum2int[other]
```

But this is error prone and cumbersome since I need to list the enum values twice. Is there a better approach?

I understand that if I use `int` values or even `IntEnum` class, I can do the comparison easily. But I want the values to be strings and compare them based on the declaration order.

Comment: Check out how this example is working and see if you can base your comparison off it. https://docs.python.org/3/howto/enum.html#planet

Comment: The example does not work for me, because their enum values are numbers. But I want to compare strings, and the comparison should be based on _the order of the values declaration_.

Comment: Is there a specific reason for the enum value type to be a string?

Comment: Yes -- the strings are coming from the network, and I am converting them to the enums by calling `MyEnum(the_nework_string)`.

Comment: Then, perhaps, a `dataclass` might work better for your needs. `Enum` is something that's usually expected to be constant during the runtime, isn't it?

Comment: If the protocol uses a limited set of strings, it is very reasonable to use a `Enum`, as all the possible values can be listed as the enum values. Later on, such enums can be compared with each other using `is`, rather than doing costly string comparisons. It's a quite common technique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`__members__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#supported-dunder-names) field, which provides an ordered mapping of `member name: member`, where the order corresponds to the definition order (or declaration order, as you call it) of your enum members. So, in your case, this could look as follows:

```py
class MyEnum(Enum):
    ONE = "one",
    TWO = "two",
    THREE = "three"

    def __le__(self, other):
        members = list(MyEnum.__members__.values())
        return members.index(self) <= members.index(other)
        # Or, equivalently:
        # names = list(MyEnum.__members__.keys())
        # return names.index(self.name) <= names.index(other.name)
```

and so on. Note that we compare the *indices* in the ordered list of members (or, equivalently, in the list of their names). This provides a generic solution with the only assumption that we defined our members (`ONE`, `TWO`, `THREE`) in the desired order – their actual values and types do not matter.

**Edit**: You could probably use the `_member_names_` field for the same purpose, as is done in [this answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58362774/7395592); however, the official documentation does not mention this alternative field, so it should probably be considered an implementation detail that cannot be relied on.

Comment: Inspired with this, I created a neat solution using member_index. U just need to derive from OrderedStrEnum: [Gist](https://gist.github.com/meta-ks/083fa6daec57175cb2d65f35bae39a17)

Answer (score 0):

You can directly access the name of your enum fields :

```
from enum import Enum

class Color(Enum):
    RED = 1
    GREEN = 2
    BLUE = 3

print(Color.RED) ## Color.RED
print(Color.RED.name) ## RED
print(Color.RED.value) ## 1
```

Hope that helps !

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately this does not work for me because my enum values must be _srings_.

Comment: This doesn't support comparison

Answer (score 0):

Based on that `Planet()` example, and I might try:

```py
import enum

class MyEnum(enum.Enum):
    ONE = ("one", 1)
    TWO = ("two", 2)
    THREE = ("three", 3)

    def __init__(self, value, ordering):
        self._value_ = value
        self.ordering = ordering

    def __lt__(self, other):
        if self.__class__ is other.__class__:
            return self.ordering < other.ordering

print(MyEnum.ONE)
print(MyEnum.ONE.value)
print(MyEnum.ONE.name)
print(MyEnum.TWO < MyEnum.THREE)
```

I think that will give you:

```
MyEnum.ONE
one
ONE
True
```

Comment: This changes the enum value, what I am trying to avoid.

Comment: In my demo I tried to show that it does not change the value. Why do you feel it does?

Comment: For my use case, the string value is coming from network. And I want to construct a enm out of that -- `MyEnum(network_string)`. If I use your approach, I'd have to map my string to the priority when construction the enum -- `MyEnum(network_string, priority_map[network_string])`. This is not great, as it equivalent to my initial approach. I want to be able to _construct it from a string only_.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `enum.auto()` function to automatically generate integer values for your string enum values based on their declaration order. This way, you can define the comparison methods based on these integer values, without having to list the enum values twice.

```py
from enum import Enum, auto
from functools import total_ordering


@total_ordering
class MyEnum(Enum):
    ONE = auto()
    TWO = auto()
    THREE = auto()

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, MyEnum):
            return False
        return self.value == other.value

    def __lt__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, MyEnum):
            return NotImplemented
        return self.value < other.value
```

Also, `class MyEnum(str, Enum):` will make your enum value type a string.